# String to array - split returning NaN value | Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I want to convert a string into an array. that works only with number value. in the following example the "border_color & border_style keys" returning NaN as value.

```js
var str ="margin_top=5&margin_bottom=5&border_color=#dfdfdf&border_style=solid";
strToArray(str);

function strToArray(str){
    str = str.replace(/\(|\)/g,'');
    var arr = str.split('&');
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var singleArr = arr[i].trim().split('=');
        var name = singleArr[0];
        var value = singleArr[1]-0;
        if (obj[name] === undefined) {
            obj[name] = value;
        }
        alert(name+': '+value);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: _`var value = singleArr[1] - 0;`_??? What do you think the results of `"#dfdfdf" - 0` and `"solid" - 0` are?

Comment: what should the outcome be? array of arrays?

Comment: my bad. I didn't see it. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NaNs are comming from trying to convert the non-numeric values into numbers (ie, `"#dfdfdf"` and `"solid"`). Before trying to convert to numbers, check if the value string is valid or not using `isNaN`:

```
var value = singleArr[1];                         // don't convert yet
if (obj[name] === undefined) {
    obj[name] = isNaN(value)? value: +value;      // if value is not a valid number, then keep it as it is (a string). Otherwise, convert it to a number (using unary + which is shorter than substracting 0)
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
var str ="margin_top=5&margin_bottom=5&border_color=#dfdfdf&border_style=solid";
strToArray(str);

function strToArray(str){
    str = str.replace(/\(|\)/g,'');
    var arr = str.split('&');
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var singleArr = arr[i].trim().split('=');
        var name = singleArr[0];
        var value = singleArr[1];
        if (obj[name] === undefined) {
            obj[name] = isNaN(value)? value: +value;
        }
        alert(name+': '+value);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure the way you want to return, but you can use: Object.values()

```js
var str ="margin_top=5&margin_bottom=5&border_color=#dfdfdf&border_style=solid";
strToArray(str);

function strToArray(str){
 str = str.replace(/\(|\)/g,'');
 var arr = str.split('&');
    var keys = []
    var values = []
 var obj = {};
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var singleArr = arr[i].trim().split('=');           
        keys.push(Object.values(singleArr)[0])
        values.push(Object.values(singleArr)[1])          
       
 }

   alert(values)
   alert(keys)

 return obj;
}
```